# Svelte render into div on exciting page dynamically using javasctipt function

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3

I have a react app which I am checking the feasibility of moving to svelte

I do not render directly to page, I create package and the package has export method which helps who ever calling the API function.

eg: -

```
const render: Render = (containerId, options) => {
  const container = document.getElementById(containerId)
  ReactModal.setAppElement(container!)
  const root = createRoot(container!)
  root.render(
    <StrictMode>{options && <App options={options} />}</StrictMode>
  )
}
```

I want to achieve the same result with svelte, is it possible? I can't see any documentation anywhere to create a function that will render the svelte on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render any Svelte component to a target of your choice using the constructor:

```js
new MySvelteComponent({
  target: element,
  props: {
  }
})
```

with `target` being an element, you could use *querySelector* to get the element.
and `props` being the exported properties of the top most component.

There are some other options, but you likely don't need them, you can find them in the [docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api-creating-a-component).